# combine three videos between specific time using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a situation where I want to combine 3 videos

The first video (guide.mp4) is the guide and the other 2 are small pieces that need to go inside the "guide"

In a graphical manner, I have the following

```
|         .---1.mp4---.                            .-----2.mp4-----.    |
|---------+-----------+------------guide.mp4-------+---------------+----|
0s        4s          9s                          18s             25s   28s
```

the 1.mp4 and 2.mp4 will cover the guide between these times.
the videos are of same size and all are .mp4 files

I am pretty sure that this is covered, but I looked a lot, but since I myself am not good in english, I dont know how I could possibly look it up with success...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you need to split videos, this might help https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking are you trying to basically replace parts of "guide.mp4" with 1.mp4 and 2.mp4?

Comment: I tried splitting the videos add puting them all together, but I need to keep the sound of guide.mp4 and if I split it then the sound is no more synced